# Ubuntu - No such file or directory #include <string>

Tags: c++, database, ubuntu

i am trying to write a code like this: (not finished)

```
 #include"header.h"
 #include<stdlib>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<libpq-fe.h>
 #include<string>

 int main(){
  std::string pguser = "XYZ";
  std::string pgpassword = "XYZ";
  std::string pghost="XYZ";
  std::string pgdbname = "XYZ";
  int i;
  PGconn *conn;
  PGresult *res;

  connstr = "user=";
  connstr += pguser;
  connstr +="password=";
  connstr += pgpassword;
  connstr +="host=";
  connstr += pghost;
  connstr +="dbname=";
  connstr += pgdbname;   

  //DB-Login
  conn = db_login(const string &user, const string &password, const string        &host, const string &dbname);
  if(conn == true){
  printf("LOGIN SUCCESFULLY");
  }else{
     printf("LOGIN FAILED");
  }

  return 0;

  }
```

My Header.h

```
 #ifndef DB_H
 #define DB_H

 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int db_login(const string &user, const string &password, const string  &host, const string &dbname);
 #endif
```

I just wanted to test it (sudo gcc main.c header.h -o test)
The Result i get is : No such file or directory #include string

I searched for an solution and tried it out but i get the same error.
(also installed -> sudo apt-get install build-essential
)

Please Help

Answer (score 3):

You are writing C++ code, but trying to compile it as C - `gcc` is the C language front-end, so use `g++` instead. Also rename your source files from `.c` to `.cpp` to get automatic support from `make(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

`#include<string>` is C++ header. You are using C++ code in .c file, it is incorrect. Probably you should rename main.c to main.cpp and use g++ instead of gcc

Answer (score 0):

For those who run into this question and use make instead of explicitly call gcc:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

will indicate whether its gcc or g++